# VM8 can not change the install directory

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

I downloaded the VM8 yesterday, but when I tried to install it, I found that all drivers are missing.

I want to install it in different folder under C:, but when I try to change the install directory, I can only it to `desktop` and `users folder`

I have been trying on my laptop and everything is fine, this only happens on my desktop, how can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the install as an administrator?